# Number of squares in a certain grouping

Tags: combinatorics, geometry, optimization

I got this problem from a professor for a class that I am taking, and I have made some progress on it but am not sure what to do now.

> Suppose I have a $2n \times 2n$ grid of unit squares where $n>1$. Suppose we partition this grid into $2 \times 2$ contiguous grids of unit squares. We have a valid grouping of these squares if:
>
> 1. At least one of the four squares in each $2$ x $2$ is in the grouping.
> 2. For any pair of squares in the grouping, there exists a sequence of squares in the grouping that starts with the first square and ends with the second square and has any two consecutive squares sharing a side.
>
> What is the minimum number of squares in the grouping, in terms of $n$?

After testing this for small values of $n$, I think that it is $\left\lceil\frac{3n^2}{2}\right\rceil - 2$. I got this through purely bashing out small cases and creating a function for it. How can I prove this is correct formula? (I think it's wrong...) If this is wrong, what is the actual formula, and proof?

Comment: Can you show your constructions for small $n$?

Comment: I  just found values and attempted to create a function. It was just really bashy. I have diagrams but can't provide pictures due to no camera.

Comment: My construction for these is that it will be a spiral.